# Run a python script every time the page is changed in Data Driven Pages? (ArcGIS 10)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, labeling, data-driven-pages

I'm setting up a Data Driven Pages mapbook mxd for a series of parking locations. I have dynamic text that updates according to the current map sheet, but I also have text that needs to update using a script. I need the dynamic text to return the LotType attribute, but it is coded using a domain, so it returns an integer rather than the string associated with the integer (such as "Special Permit", "Fac/Staff", "Metered", etc). I have a VBscript from an old MPS Atlas MXD that returns the associated string, but I don't know of any way to use a script with non-MPS Atlas dynamic text. Is it possible to embed a python script into the MXD that runs whenever the user changes pages in the map book? Or is there a way to include scripts within the core Arc10 dynamic text?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this

1. Add a field to the Area of Interest Feature Class specifying the value you want to be displayed and then you can edit the dynamic text so that it points to the new field (DDP does not work on Joined Fields)
2. If you used to have MPS Atas, maybe just upgrade to Production Mapping which includes the MPS Atlas component. At ArcGIS 10 the MPS Atlas portion of Production Mapping is not available separately so I do understand if this is not an option but still there.